# find-name-dired : save selection of files for reuse?

Tags: dired, find-dired

I try to use `find-name-dired`, everything works out as expected. Is there a way to save the selection of files for reuse?

Comment: You seem to be asking two different questions: (1) save the names of the files in the resulting Dired buffer and (2) "specify the selection rules by multiple paths". I removed the second question. Please post it separately - only one question per post. (And I don't know what you mean by that second question - please clarify it when you post it separately.)

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of the (absolute names of the) files in a Dired directory (including one produced by `find-name-dired` etc.), just use `t` with no files marked, to mark them all, and then use `(dired-get-marked-files)`. (You can use `t` again to unmark them all.)

You can save such a list in various ways, depending on what you mean - e.g. set a variable to it and save the variable, e.g., with `savehist-additional-variables` (library `savehist.el`).

---

You can use `(dired (cons BUFNAME FILES))` to open Dired on your (saved) list of files, where `BUFNAME` is the name you want to give to the Dired buffer and `FILES` is your list of saved file names.

This uses a little-known feature of function `dired` (likewise `dired-other-window` etc.): If the `DIRNAME` arg you give it is, instead of a string that names a directory, a list of strings, then it uses the first string in that list as the Dired buffer name and the other strings as the file names to list.

This means that `dired` can create a Dired buffer with an *arbitrary list of files and directories*, from anywhere - even in different trees of your file system.

---

If you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) ([`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el)) then you can use command `diredp-dired-for-files` to create such a Dired buffer of arbitrary files *interactively*. You're prompted for the files/dirs to include in the listing.

But see also my other two answers here, for easy ways to create such a snapshot Dired listing.  And see [Dired Snapshot](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus#DiredSnapshot) and section **Saving and Restoring Dired Listings** in the `Commentary` of `dired+.el`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) ([`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el)) then you can use command
`diredp-marked` (or `diredp-marked-other-window`, which is bound to `C-M-*`) to create a Dired buffer that's a *snapshot* of the marked buffers in the Dired buffer produced by `find-name-dired` (and other `find-dired` commands).

And with a multiple-`C-u` prefix arg you can do the same but ignore markings and instead pick up all of the files:

> A prefix `ARG` that is non-positive or a single `C-u` means prompt for
> `ls` listing switches, as in command `dired`.
>
> A prefix `ARG` also specifies the files to use instead of the marked
> files (any markings are ignored), as follows:
>
> If `ARG` is positive or negative, use the files named on the next `ARG`
> lines.  E.g., `1` or `-1`: use the file on the current line; `3` or `-3`:
> use the file on the current line and those on the following 2 lines.
>
> **If `ARG` is `C-u C-u`, `C-u C-u C-u`, or `C-u C-u C-u C-u`, use *all*
> files in the Dired buffer**, where:
>
> - `C-u C-u` includes only *files* - *no directories*
> - `C-u C-u C-u` includes directories *except* `.` and `..`
> - `C-u C-u C-u C-u` includes *all* directories (even `.` and `..`)
>
> If `ARG` is otherwise non-`nil` (e.g. 0, `M--` or a single `C-u`), use
> the file or dir of the current line (same as `ARG` = `-1`).

The listing is a snapshot, meaning that the fact that it results from a `find` command is lost.  You can access it directly, without re-`find`ing, to save searching.  Of course this also means that any changes that `find` would notice won't be reflected in use of the snapshot.

---

OK, but then how to persist this snapshot across Emacs sessions?  For that you need library [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus). Then you can just bookmark the snapshot Dired buffer.

You need Bookmark+ for this because a vanilla Emacs Dired bookmark doesn't really record anything useful.  With Bookmark+ a Dired bookmark records the current state of the Dired buffer: its marked files, inserted subdirs, etc. -- including, for a snapshot listing, the complete set of files and dirs listed.

When you jump to the bookmark your Dired snapshot is restored.  The bookmark is a persistent cache of the set of files and dirs found by your `find` command (e.g. `find-name-dired`).

See [Dired Snapshot](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus#DiredSnapshot) and section **Saving and Restoring Dired Listings** in the `Commentary` of `dired+.el`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) ([`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el)) then there's another solution, which doesn't require that you also use library [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus).

That solution is to use Dired+ command **`diredp-define-snapshot-dired-commands`** in the Dired buffer that results from your `find` command. That creates two commands (same-window and other-window) that each create a snapshot Dired buffer with the files and dirs listed by your `find` command.

When you create these commands a buffer pops up with their Lisp definitions (defuns).  Copy either or both definitions to your init file, to give you persistent access to the snapshot Dired buffer.

See [Dired Snapshot](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus#DiredSnapshot) and section **Saving and Restoring Dired Listings** in the `Commentary` of `dired+.el`.

Answer (score 0):

Just run `M-x my-save-current-buffer`, then open saved file in Emacs.

Here is the code,

```
(defun my-save-current-buffer ()
  "Save current buffer (Dired, Grep, ...) to re-use in the future."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((file (read-file-name "Save buffer to file (its extension must be \"el\"): "))
         (content (buffer-string))
         (can-save-p t)
         (header (format "-*- mode:%s; default-directory: \"%s\" -*-\n"
                         (replace-regexp-in-string "-mode" "" (format "%s" major-mode))
                         default-directory)))
    (when file
      ;; double check file name extension
      (unless (equal (file-name-extension file) "el")
        (setq file (concat (file-name-base file) ".el")))

      (when (file-exists-p file)
        (setq can-save-p
              (yes-or-no-p (format "File %s exists.  Override it?" fil))))
      (when can-save-p
        (with-temp-buffer
          (insert header)
          (insert content)
          ;; write buffer content into file
          (write-region (point-min) (point-max) file))))))

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (lambda () (unless dired-subdir-alist (dired-build-subdir-alist))))
```

Notes:

- `my-save-current-buffer` is a generic function. It could be used to save any kind of buffer
- `dired-build-subdir-alist` need be called in `dired-mode-hook`
- If you use `global-auto-revert-mode`, `global-auto-revert-non-file-buffers` should stay in its default value `nil`. Or else `dired-revert` is called which screws up the dired buffer content
- I learned the techniques from studying code of `ivy`.